# Microservice between my own application and a logging application to structure logging

Tags: c#, microservices

I'm trying to find a good example which explains me how I can build a micro-service that I can put between my own application and a logging application like seq. In this way I'll try to put the logging data in the same destination an I can switch easily from those logging application so I don't have to edit my entire code. Is there a way to do this and maybe a example which explains this. I've already googled for it but I didn't found any clear explanations.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tutorial are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Also, your question sounds a bit like you better go and get an understanding about SOA, then what micro-services are and what architectural conditions lead to use them.

Comment: Why do you need a `microservice` for this? Perhaps you could simply get away with a specific log adapter for your logging framework on your application side, for example, an adapter for `Serilog`

Comment: Modern logging libraries like Serilog and NLog have multiple outputs (Sinks or Targets) that they can log to, no microservice needed. And often where they log to can be controlled by modifying a configuration file. Seems like you're trying to invent a new solution instead of using what already exists.

Comment: I know that SOA might be better. It is for my internship next year and the company asked for an microservice. Thats why I asked here for some tips and maybe some examples.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion building a microservice for this is unnecessary complication of your architecture.

For decoupling you can simply use a `Serilog` sink for `Seq`

There are sinks for `Serilog` for `Seq`:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-seq
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Seq/

There are also `Seq` appenders for `log4net` and `NLog` here https://github.com/datalust/seq-client

Comment: Thanks I Will take a look at it!

Answer (score -2):

You can create microservice to log in database which will be hosted somewhere accessible to your application. Currently I have created console application with unity container and NancyFx. You may like to explore further per your requirements. Can you please share any details on technical issues apart from generic problems.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is for my internship next year. The company wants a microservice but I already recommended Them SOA so Ik hoped that maybe you had some good tips and suggestions for the microservices. The technical issue is that their logging data now ends in different sources so they want to put it in a central point and they want to switch easily from logging applications. I Just don't know how In could do this with a microservice.

Comment: @Yannick: please talk to an enterprise architect.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I'm a beginning software engineer so I don't know where I can find an architect that fast. What I do understand is that SOA might be a better solution than microservices so I will take a look at SOA. I already worked with this at school so I know the basics.

Comment: @Yannick, you said: "The company wants a microservice". If the company wants it they will have made the decision thanks to an architect recommending this. If they don't have an architect please question the requirement of a micro-service. From what you tell, a micro-service makes no sense.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst there might be an architect over there but the main reason they want a microservice is because one of the programmers recommends it (he thinks it is better, faster, etc.) . I know he haven't look further so that's why I also look for some better solutions.